# List not getting updated

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I haven't worked with list before so pardon me if this is a simple mistake. Am trying to update the list dynamically when ever the user want to see his/her current location. When the user clicks on a button current location(lat and lon) are fetched and inserted into list. My list is not getting updated. It is not even showing the data which is within the `ArrayList` am confused.

this is how i declare my list in `onCreate()`

```
listView        = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomList(StartCalc.this, 0, 0);        
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

adding lat and lon to arraylist

```
CustomList.lat.add(_CURLAT);
CustomList.lon.add(_CURLON);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

my CustomList class

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


int _COUNT;
public static ArrayList<Double> lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> lon = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> ele = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> dis = new ArrayList<Double>();

private final Activity context;

TextView location_list_textViewNO;
TextView location_list_lat;
TextView location_list_lon;
TextView location_list_ele;
TextView location_list_dis;


public CustomList(Activity context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_list, textViewResourceId);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this._COUNT  = textViewResourceId;

    lat.add(2.333);
    lon.add(5.03333);
    ele.add(5.77777777);
    dis.add(7.2222);    

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list, null, true);

    location_list_textViewNO = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_textViewNO);
    location_list_lat = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_lat);
    location_list_lon = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_lon);
    location_list_ele = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_ele);
    location_list_dis = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_dis);

    location_list_textViewNO.setText("A");
    location_list_lat.setText("LAT: " + lat.get(position));
    location_list_lon.setText("LON: " + lon.get(position));
    location_list_ele.setText("ELE: " + ele.get(position));
    location_list_dis.setText("DIS: " + dis.get(position)); 

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after new items added into arraylist.

Comment: Yes i have added that after adding data to list.

Comment: Initially also it is not displaying anything or it is not updating.

Comment: you an see sum values am directly adding to listeven that values dont appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling

`listview.notifyDataSetChanged();`

after adding lat/long

Also change your adapter as following:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<Double>{//Set Double as data type


int _COUNT;
public static ArrayList<Double> lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> lon = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> ele = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> dis = new ArrayList<Double>();

private final Activity context;

TextView location_list_textViewNO;
TextView location_list_lat;
TextView location_list_lon;
TextView location_list_ele;
TextView location_list_dis;


public CustomList(Activity context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_list, textViewResourceId,lat);//<---- Set one of the list as the 4th argument of super constructor 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this._COUNT  = textViewResourceId;

    lat.add(2.333);
    lon.add(5.03333);
    ele.add(5.77777777);
    dis.add(7.2222);    

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list, null, true);

    location_list_textViewNO = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_textViewNO);
    location_list_lat = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_lat);
    location_list_lon = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_lon);
    location_list_ele = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_ele);
    location_list_dis = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_dis);

    location_list_textViewNO.setText("A");
    location_list_lat.setText("LAT: " + lat.get(position));
    location_list_lon.setText("LON: " + lon.get(position));
    location_list_ele.setText("ELE: " + ele.get(position));
    location_list_dis.setText("DIS: " + dis.get(position)); 

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Comment: yes i have already done that i missed that while posting the question. and did try changing to Double but tht didn't made any change.

Comment: Also in super add add following:

super(context, R.layout.location_list, textViewResourceId,lat); 

the 4th argument is one of the arraylist of double type

Answer (score 0):

to update yout listview contents you need to notify dataset changed to your adapter.
Try calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

CustomList.lat.add(_CURLAT);
CustomList.lon.add(_CURLON);

Hope this helps.

try passing default values for 'lat' and 'lon' in your adapter constructor. like this ,

```
public CustomList(Activity context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,Double lat_val = 2.333, Double lon_val = 5.03333) {
super(context, R.layout.location_list, textViewResourceId,lat);//<---- Set one of the list as the 4th argument of super constructor 
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.context = context;
this._COUNT  = textViewResourceId;

lat.add(lat_val);
lon.add(lon_val);
ele.add(5.77777777);
dis.add(7.2222);
```

}

Comment: yes i have already done that i missed that while posting the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**Cut** the below lines

```
public static ArrayList<Double> lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> lon = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> ele = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<Double> dis = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and paste in your **MainActivity**

because every time if you refresh that adapter that will **initilize**  **again** and **again**..

and also your adding items inside `CustomList` that's wrong add that items also in the MainActivity.